# Wordpress - ajax load more plugin showing tags

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am usign Ajax Load More plugin for showing post. I Want to my posts to show tags, that user insert when he is writting posts. Does any know how can I do that.

I tried to add  tags (in ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php) in initial query arguments

```
     $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
        'post_type'                => $postType,
        'posts_per_page'           => $posts_per_page,
        'offset'                   => $offset + ($posts_per_page*$page),
        'order'                    => $order,
        'orderby'                  => $orderby,
        'post_status'              => $post_status,
        'ignore_sticky_posts'      => true,
        'paged'                    => $paged,
        'tags'                      =>  $tags
    );
```

This doesn't work, does any have some example or idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you need filter posts by multiple tags - you should use `'tag__in' => array('tags')` instead of `'tags'`. Or if single tag - 'tag' => 'slug' or 'tag_id' => 'tag_id'. See WP_Query [refference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#tag-parameters)